# Multiple where conditions on eloquent model with optional where on relationship

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I have table `training_schedules`

- id (int, pk)
- course_reference (varchar)
- start_date (date)
- end_date (date)
- year_id (int, fk)

and `years`

- id (int, pk)
- value (int)

Now I want to create a search query using the TrainingSchedule eloquent model. I want to search by `course_reference` (using like) and `start_date(optional)` based on month (dropdownlist on form) and year (optional)

optional conditions means I will check if the form data for the fields are filled on the search form. If not I will just skip those conditions.

How can I achieve this using Eloquent ORM? if not, how to do it on another way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a query over multiple calls. So something like the following will probably do what you're looking for:

```
// start query off with a non-optional query
$results = TrainingSchedule::whereLike('course_reference', Input::get('course_reference'));

// only if we were sent a start date, add it to the query
if (Input::has('start_date')) {
    $results->whereStartDate(Input::get('start_date'));
}

// if we were sent a month, ensure start date's month is the same month as the one passed in
if (Input::has('month')) {
    $results->where(DB::raw('MONTH(`start_date`)'), Input::get('month'));
}

// only if we were sent a year, add it to the query
if (Input::has('year')) {
    $results->whereHas('year', function ($query) { $query->whereValue(Input::get('year')); });
}

 // get actual results from db
$results = $results->get();
```

Comment: yes I came up with something like that. now I am having problem with the month part

Comment: Update your question with how the month stuff is worked out and I'll see if I can help - right now, from the info you give, I can't see what you need to do with month. Presumably it's something to do with start_date and/or end_date, but I'm not sure.

Comment: its on the post. I want to filter using the posted form data of month (dropdownlist) so Jan = 1, Feb = 2. etc. how can I use those integer values to filter the date column (start_date) on database.

Comment: Okay I've updated my answer to take care of the month too. Give it a go, as it may not be perfect but certainly should get you going. I've treated it as optional input though your original question looks like it's not optional.

Comment: tnx for updating. That would work but its not indexable check my question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22470657/how-to-query-only-by-month-on-date-input-and-ignore-the-year-and-day-considering/22470718?noredirect=1#22470718

Comment: and sorry for the typo. the year value from posted data should be the actual year and not the year's ID. So I need to query from relationship not by year_id on same Model (TrainingSchedule) but on the Year(model)

Comment: Ahh, so you need to join to `year` and check its `value` column? That certainly starts getting a little more complicated. (Though is there any reason you don't use the `year`'s `id` field?) Either way, my method is still sound - you just need to use Eloquent's [`has` method](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#querying-relations). As for whether using MySQL's `MONTH()` function is indexable, it's probably not, but if you have an index on start_date it may help. Try it with an `EXPLAIN` and see. I think if you really want indexability, you'll need to implement the month yourself as a column.

Comment: now thats what I need tnx. I'll just leave the month as it is for now and change it when found another solution.

i dont want to use the id because if I use it as GET request. the query parameter is not descriptive like for example id of year 2014 = 2. on url it will be /?reference=someRef&year=2