# How to query only by month on date input and ignore the year and day considering indexing or performance on database in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I have this table

`training_schedules`

- id
- course_reference
- start_date(date)
- end_date(date)
- year_id(int, fk)

on my form, I have dropdownlist for the month, and another one for the year.
Now as you can see there is a mismatch on the `month from form` and `database column`. How can I filter the `start_date` or `end_date` column using only the integer value from the dropdownlist and ignore the `day` and `year` part of the db column?

I saw some examples but using raw query and using date functions of database which is not good if you consider performance because it is not indexable.

Can I achieve this using Eloquent/Fluent Api of Laravel?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using mysql 
u can use the month() function to get month from date

For further clarification please visit the [link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html)

Comment: is it indexable or it will iterate all the records? As I had mentioned on my post.